# Dynamic LINQ nested selects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to come up with a Dynamic LINQ query that will let me select properties from nested  entity collections. I want to get a list of roles with some associated user information for each role. I will, of course, actually be returning role information, but I left that out of this example because it is trivial.

This LINQ query gives me the information I need:

```
ROLES.Select(r => new { ID = r.ID, USER_ROLES = r.USER_ROLES.Select(ur => new { ID = ur.ID, USER = new { ID = ur.USER.ID, USERNAME = ur.USER.USERNAME } } ) })
```

The results will be serialized to JSON and should contain:

```
[
  {ID: 1, USER_ROLES: [
    {ID: 100, USER: {ID: 3, USERNAME: 'code0100fun'} }
  ] },
  {ID: 2, USER_ROLES: [
    {ID: 100, USER: {ID: 3, USERNAME: 'code0100fun'} },
    {ID: 101, USER: {ID: 4, USERNAME: 'somedude'   } }
  ] }
]
```

What would the Dynamic LINQ (System.Linq.Dynamic) query for this look like?

Comment: If you have a static query that gives you all of the information you need then why do you want a dynamic query?  What about the query do you need to be changing?

Comment: I need to change the properties that are returned by the query based on parameters passed in a web request. The solution needs to work on all entities, so building static queries using a lambda builder would require code changes for each new type of entity I add.

Comment: I see this was asked a long time ago, but did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @user2325333 Not supported in System.Linq.Dynamic . Supported in System.Linq.Dynamic.Core (fork of System.Linq.Dynamic).